# Accuracy of automatic (machine) translation of two languages in same language family

Tags: language-families, machine-translation, turkic-languages

Are there any statistic on how accuracy the automated (program/machine) transition from one language to another language of the same language family?

For example from turkey to azerbaijan, uzbek, turkmen etc (turkic langs)
They all have same logic (suffix addition order etc).

Comment: I suspect "same family" as a binary distinction isn't very useful. German, Spanish, and Hindi are in the same family, but a lot more distantly related than, say, German, Swedish, and Dutch. (Not to mention that sometimes two closely-related languages can have major differences in grammar, while sometimes a broad family with dozens of languages can be grammatically very consistent.)

Comment: Also, given how much machine translation work involves English, I suspect you'd be a lot better off looking for comparisons between, say, English/German, English/Hindi, and English/Turkish than, between say, Turkish/Azerbaijani, Turkish/Kipchak, and Turkish/something-not-Turkic-at-all. Would those English-based statistics be acceptable?

Comment: Anyway, I know Google has published some results on the accuracy of GNMT and its predecessor. For example, [this blog post](https://www.argotrans.com/blog/accurate-google-translate-2018/) says that (where the metric is apparently native speakers evaluating translations subjectively on a scale of 0 to 6) English/French scores 5.43, while English/Chinese scores only 4.3, although they don't give the source for that.

Comment: @abarnert The languages in question are much more closely related than IE languages, a better comparison would be Germanic languages.

Comment: @AdamBittlingmayer Which languages in question? I already paralleled Turkish/Azerbaijani with English/German, two Germanic languages. I was under the impression that Kipchak is significantly farther away. Would Turkish/Chuvash be a better comparison for English/Hindi, or are even they closer than that? Should it be, say, English/Frisian/German :: Turkish/Azerbaijani/Chuvash instead of English/German/Hindi? (I don't think that changes my point at all, even if so, but still, interesting to know.)

Comment: @abarnert I am not a linguist, and therefore, under one language family, I mean such a language pair like Ukrainian / Belarusian, Uzbek / Kazakh, Tatar / Bashkir, etc. I know that Hindi and German are in the same language family, but this not this way. as close as Uzbek / Kazakh.
I also know that there are still some discussions about which language to include or not for a particular family.

Comment: @UserKa My point is that much of the research, and much of the actual production work, involves English. If you specifically want/need to know about Turkic languages, ask about them of course. But if you're interested in the generic question "does translating related languages make translation easier?", you're almost certainly better off asking about pairs with English than pairs with Turkish, for practical reasons. (And that's even _before_ I thought about the bridging issue in Adam Bittlingmayer's answer, which makes that much more true.)

Comment: As a Czech, I've often translated Slovak and I've never spot Google Translator would make an error.

Comment: @Probably Maybe that's because google translate use direct translation between Czech and Slovak. But there are no official documents that indicate which pairs use direct translation.

Comment: @UserKa That's for sure

Answer (score 6):

*Update: Much has changed since 2019.  I added updates at the bottom.*

---

You're right to suspect that the accuracy can potentially be very good, but, in practice, unfortunately, as of 2019, most of the major systems - those from Google, Microsoft, Baidu, Yandex, Facebook, Amazon, DeepL and so on - use [bridging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pivot_language) via English for almost all pairs, even closely related ones.

The reason for this is simply pragmatic.  Those systems support 100+ languages, and thus there are 10000+ pairs.  Most of those pairs, like Tamil-Basque, are not in high demand, and there is not much training data for them anyway.  That's even true for pairs of related languages like Romanian-Galician.

Engineering-wise, even if one could create data for, train and evaluate all those pairs, it is also just a lot of effort to deploy and maintain 10000+ systems in production at scale, even with NMT - end-to-end models.

So, incredibly, even very closely related major languages are not translated directly, but via English.  You can easily test this, for example for Spanish-Portuguese, which are almost as close as Turkish and Azerbaijani, and have much much more training data.

[image]

In this example, *He was killed by a bat* is ambiguous in English - it's not clear if the flying mouse or the wooden stick is meant.

(If you use machine translation API and are interested catching such casualties of bridging and other errors, you can try machine translation risk prediction like [ModelFront](https://modelfront.com).)

Turkish-Azerbaijani is actually one of the lucky pairs that does have a direct system in at least one direction on Google Translate.  Let's test it.  *bat* doesn't work as well in Turkish since they basically just say *baseball stick*, so we can use the T-V distinction as an example of something that English cannot represent.

[image]
[image]

We've confirmed that a translation via English would probably lose it.

[image]

And, yes, Turkish-Azerbaijani still works as it should.  So we can conclude it's direct.  (Although note that the bridging could pass along some hints, so we should test this really well before making strong conclusions.)

One reason for this approach is that it would be hard to get the accuracy for English-Azerbaijani.  There is simply much more English-Turkish and Turkish-Azerbaijani data.

So, about the accuracy, well it *could* potentially be one of the best pairs, but it needs more data and more work than has been put into it.  As far as I know, English-Portuguese outperforms for example English-Dutch and even English-Frisian on all major engines, even though Frisian is probably the language closest to English supported by any major system.

The blocker here is really that most societies are not home to a major technology company.  The major systems are made in the US, China and Russia, without exception.  The rest of the world just does not produce much.  The closest candidates are Systran, which is not very competitive in recent decades, and DeepL, which only covers European languages, and still focuses on pairs with English, English being the lingua franca of Europe.  Turkey and Azerbaijan inflicted braindrain on themselves throughout the 20th century, and show no signs of stopping, so my bet is that Yandex will be the first to build direct systems for more obscure Turkic pairs.

For more context see my answers to [Which languages are Google Translate best at translating?](https://www.quora.com/Which-languages-are-Google-Translate-best-at-translating/answer/Adam-Bittlingmayer) and [Which two languages is machine translation worst at translating between?](https://www.quora.com/Which-two-languages-is-machine-translation-worst-at-translating-between/answer/Adam-Bittlingmayer).

——

#### Updates

Looking back 3 years later, a few points need updating.

1. Russia is also inflicting brain drain on itself and the Yandex team.
2. DeepL, made in Germany, is now a major player and [supports dozens of languages](https://machinetranslate.org/deepl), including East Asian languages.
3. Massively multilingual models - that don’t require bridging - are moving towards production.

Comment: Does Baidu bridge everything through English as much as the western companies? (I can imagine that when they started, and were trying to ramp up to near-Google-equivalency as quickly as possible, they used whatever corpus data was available, which was mostly English/___ translations. But they've had a few years since then to build up and train on Mandarin/___. And it seems like that would give them a competitive advantage against Google/etc., and also be something the government would encourage/facilitate.)

Comment: How can I find out which language using bridge English or not. Are there any documents? How did you find out that Turkish / Azerbaijani has direct system? Or is this just your guess based on your example?

Comment: And another question (I don't think that I should create new question topic for this) Do you know any translation service that uses one of the Turkic languages as a bridge (pivot) language?

Comment: @abarnert No, Yandex, Baidu, Youdao etc may bridge through Russian or Chinese, and of course they do x-Russian and x-Chinese directly, but that has the same issue.  Just like Google, Facebook, Microsoft and Amazon, 90% of their pairs are bridged not direct.

Comment: @UserKa Look at my answer, I showed you how can you find out that a system is bridging via English (Spanish-Portuguese).  It's hard to prove that a system is *not* bridging via English, but if you test enough and see no signs that it is, which are usually obvious, then you can start to assume it's not.

Comment: @UserKa Sort of and no.  Firstly, you don't want a system that uses a Turkic language as a bridge language, you want a system that translates directly between two Turkic languages.  Sort of, as I mentioned, on major systems some pairs like English-Azerbaijani may go via Turkish.  No, there is no major system that is using a Turkic language as a bridge language generally, because there is frankly no Turkic society that produces serious tech companies.  Even Western Europe, which has much better education and tech companies, has failed to produce a top search engine or IaaS platform.

Comment: @AdamBittlingmayer OK, that makes sense. Obviously bridging through Chinese is no better than bridging through English for converting between two Turkic languages; I was just asking out of curiosity.

Comment: Although, now that I think about it… it seems plausible that building a system with a small handful of bridging languages (4N is not the same problem as N^2…) instead of just one might work better (maybe by having different networks that compete over the same translation and picking the one with the highest confidence or something?), although the cost of building that handful of networks might easily overwhelm the benefit. Do you know if anyone's tried that? (This is probably getting way off-topic for the OP's question, so feel free to just tell me that if you think it's appropriate…)

Comment: @abarnert Is there a Chinese translation apps or APIs support a Turkic language anyway, let alone multiple?  Like I said, my bet is on Yandex, which already has Uzbek, Turkish, Azerbaijani, Kyrgyz and Kazakh like Google, and also Tatar.

Comment: @abarnert Re multiple bridge languages, again, my bet is on Yandex, but technically Google, Microsoft etc have it, it's just very very imbalanced, ie the 2nd bridge language is used for orders of magnitude fewer pairs than the 1st, and they're not somehow combined in any way, to my knowledge.

Comment: I know little about the Chinese translation apps available. I wouldn't be surprised if Baidu handled the Turkic languages of Xinjiang, but I wouldn't be surprised if they didn't, either. Honestly, the only reason I asked about Baidu was that it was the only one in your list "Google, Microsoft, Baidu, Facebook, Amazon and so on" that isn't American.

Comment: @abarnert Thanks, mistake on my part.  Added Yandex and DeepL now.

Comment: @AdamBittlingmayer > " ie the 2nd bridge language is used for orders of magnitude fewer pairs than the 1st, and they're not somehow combined in any way, to my knowledge" I dont understand this sentence very well (eng is not my native lang (btw, my russian and tatar)) Did you mean that Yandex has a lot more experiance (database/neural network education) than google and other service? Only for that reason you think yandex better for turkic/turkic translation?
Since if both service using their own bridge lang (russian or english) then english-trukic more simply to translate than russian-turkic.

Comment: @AdamBittlingmayer You said that if you need to find out if there is any bridge language or not, I have to check it myself manually. But it is not 100% guaranteed. Do you know if there is an official announcement (of any company) that language pairs have direct translation or not?
Or maybe there are some inside information was leaked from google/yandex management?

Comment: What I mean is: a major system may use a 2nd bridge language for some pairs, but still only for a very small fraction of the total pairs.

Comment: No, the reason I bet on Yandex is that Yandex just puts more priority on the Anatolian, Caucasian and Central Asian *markets*, and there are Turkic languages (Tatarca, pered vsem) native to Russia.  US companies don't know or care much.  There is no linguistic reason, it's economic.

Comment: Another example of market-driven priorities is that Yandex offers direct translation (no bridging) for pairs like Russian-Turkish, simply because its focus is Russophone users, not Anglophone ones.

Comment: @UserKa You can try, but it's extremely doubtful you will get information, especially information that is complete and updated.  Just try yourself like I showed you for the pairs of interest.

Comment: @UserKa Information like that doesn't get leaked from management. But sometimes it gets released because an engineer wants to blog about it, or because marketing thinks a whitepaper showing how they do something more cleverly than Google would be helpful in enterprise sales, or because they file a patent, or whatever. It's almost random what technical information tech companies release that way. But asking them directly "How do you X?" is usually pointless; it makes them think X might be a valuable trade secret, so if they haven't already published it, they're less likely to do so now.